# HttpModule wont fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpmodule, file-upload

I have an httpmodule class in my class library called API and the httpmodule in this class library is called FileUploadModule.vb.

I have registered the httpmodule in the `system.web` section with `<add name="FileUploadModule" type="FileUploadModule, API" />`.

Is this the correct way to register an httpmodule?

Why won't my httpmodule fire when i debug the vb.net 2.0 framework web application?

```
Public Class FileUploadModule
Implements IHttpModule

Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Dispose
End Sub

Public Sub Init(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
    AddHandler context.BeginRequest, AddressOf OnBeginRequest
End Sub

Public Sub OnBeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim app As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
    app.Context.Response.Write("ddddddddddddddddddd")
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article on stack overflow that helped me also and @adt pointed me in the right direction aswell and got it to work,

Basically i added registered the httpmodule in:-

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
     <add name="FileUploadModuleControl" type="API.FileUploadModuleControl"/>
  </modules>
```

And it worked!.

The article i found usefule on stackoverflow was at ["500 Internal Server Error" when adding HttpModule in my Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573325/500-internal-server-error-when-adding-httpmodule-in-my-website).

Answer (score 1):

problem seems about registering.

```
<httpModules>
    <add type="classname, assemblyname" name="modulename"  />
<httpModules>
```

is your assembly name is API?

Comment: @adt Yes the assembly name is API and the classname is FileUploadModule, but ive tried this also and no luck, the break points arent hitting the code.

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/02/httpmodule-for-timing-requests.aspx can you try this example? this works without any doubt.

Comment: @Trikam is your problem about not being able to debug it or you cant see ddddddd every rewuest on your application?

Comment: @adt, no it didnt work for me, is there any settings i need to add to the module tag or iis? im using windows 7. I had the same issue when implementing a httphandler, but i got it working by adding '<add name="FileUpload" verb="POST" path="JqueryPluginTest.aspx" type="API.FileUploadHandler"/>' and it worked but im using iggpmodule so it should be different to using httphandler.

Comment: add httpmodule to system.webserver of web.config file. or add it by using UI of IIS. this problem is definetly about registering module to web.config :)

Comment: Also note that if you're using IIS 7 (or IIS Express) the <add> node goes under **<modules>** in <system.webServer>, not <httpModules>.