# Web.Config httpModules Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I updated my `web.config` to support URL Rewriting but when I use it on my web server it shows the error:

> Internal Server Error The server
>   encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to
>   complete your request. Please contact
>   the server administrator to inform of
>   the time the error occurred and of
>   anything you might have done that may
>   have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

My web.config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" 
             requirePermission="false"                           
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
  </configSections>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/subjects/(.+).aspx" to="~/subject.aspx?ebook-subject=$1"/>
    <rewrite url="~/books/(.+).aspx" to="~/book.aspx?ebook-name=$1"/>
    <rewrite url="~/booklinks/(.+).aspx" to="~/booklink.aspx"/>
    <rewrite url="~/subcategories/(.+).aspx" to="~/subcategory.aspx?ebook-subcategory=$1"/>
    <rewrite url="~/categories/(.+).aspx" to="~/category.aspx?ebook-category=$1"/>
    <rewrite url="~/explainsubjects/(.+).aspx" to="~/explainsubject.aspx?ebook-subject=$1"/>

    <rewrite url="~/search/search.aspx" to="~/search.aspx"/>
    <rewrite url="~/search/searchresults.aspx" to="~/searchresults.aspx"/>
  </rewriter>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" 
           type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
    </customErrors>
    <pages/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["500 Internal Server Error" when adding HttpModule in my Website??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573325/500-internal-server-error-when-adding-httpmodule-in-my-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573325/500-internal-server-error-when-adding-httpmodule-in-my-website) solved my problem.

Comment: thats why I am asking for IIS version. I was thinking the same issue, but before answering I am confirming from you.

Comment: Yes, but I didnt read ur comment before I got it through another question at stackoverflow itself. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 1):

I take it you have tried on the server itself and checked the event logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this exception is thrown when the contents of the config file are invalid.

try taking out all the redirects and see if the error occurs.

the httpModule and configSections sections look ok to me.

EDIT: also, as @mikeblake says, check the logs